# Handle object mapper exception and missing return statement

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I am contemplating throwing a `RuntimeException` inside the catch block to solve the missing return statement.

What would be way to handle this situation?

I think throwing an exception of some kind instead of return some meaningless value. .

```
private String tryObjMapper(Object obj) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //missing return statement
}
```

Comment: depends on what you want to be the fallback/default value

Comment: maybe throw new RuntimeException(e) or similar in your catch. You don't need an additional return in that scenario

Comment: If you can't handle the error there, re-throw the exception and let a higher level handle it.

Comment: Possibly `throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Unable to convert obj %s to string using objectMapper", obj));`

Comment: It probably makes sense to simply avoid catching the exception and modify the signature of your method to reflect that it can throw it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to be the fallback/default value or error handling

You have 2 main options (with 2 sub options):

1.A.Throw the exception:

```
private String tryObjMapper(Object obj) throws JsonProcessingException  {    
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
}
```

1.B.Rethrow `RuntimeException` (or custom unchecked exception)

```
private String tryObjMapper(Object obj) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to map obj +" obj, e);
    }
}
```

2.A.Define a default value on error

```
private String tryObjMapper(Object obj) {
    try {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;//or other default value
}
```

2.B.Define a default value with a single return statement:

```
private String tryObjMapper(Object obj) {
    String retVal = null;//or other default value
    try {
        retVal = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retVal ;
}
```

Consider logging exception using logger and not using `e.printStackTrace()`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to handle it is to return `null` at both catch block ant the end of the function. You must check the returnee from the function whether `null` or not before usage.
Note: This solution is suitable if only you can't change the signature of the function to declare that it throws an exception. Otherwise, go with the signature update.